# Can I authenticate to Artifactory or Nexus repositories via SSH?

Tags: authentication, continuous-integration, nexus, maven

We're looking for a maven repo with a better browser interface, and a question has come up about whether plaintext passwords in .m2/settings.xml can be replaced with an SSH key when using either Artifactory or Nexus. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artifactory will not authenticate with SSH keys in the maven settings.xml; if you're after a more secure way to authenticate other than the clear-text passwords, it does give you the option of generating and using encrypted passwords.
See this for more info: [Centrally Secure Passwords](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Centrally+Secure+Passwords)